# Silverlight Listbox: Binding does not get updated

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, observablecollection

I have a Wizard control that has multiple steps. Controls that are not visible get removed from the visual tree. I have a `ListBox` on one page, that binds to an `ObservableCollection<T>`. When items get added or removed to that `ListBox`on one page, the `ListBox` on another page (with the same `ItemsSource`), the binding on the other page does not get updated. I hope this explains my problem clearly enough.

How do I get this binding to update when the page gets added to the visual tree again ?

Comment: How are you adding or removing items to that listbox?

Comment: Every page represents one step?

Comment: Every page represents one step, yes. I'm not adding and removing to the listbox directly, but adding to the ObservableCollection<T>

Comment: Let me get this straight: you have two (or more) listboxes that are not visible at the same time, booth are feed with the same ObservableCollection. When any of these is not visible you fully remove it from the visual tree ¿but you keep a reference somewhere right? When one of these needs to be visible you re-add it to the visual tree and you see that previous changes are not populated. ¿Am I right?

Comment: Yes @NestorArturo, when items are removed and then added they get added twice. Clearing the list works, but adding an item again will add it twice, or three times, depending on how many times it repeats.

Comment: Would like to see how are you adding and removing the Listboxes from the visual tree.

Comment: Have you tried manually calling PropertyChanged events for your bound properties at the time of the page getting re-added to the visual tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. I was able to remove a ListBox from the visual tree, add objects to the ObservableCollection, and when I add it to the visual tree, items are actually updated.

Try working around your problem by setting visibility to Collapsed rather than removing from Visual Tree.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.listBox1.ItemsSource = o;
        this.listBox2.ItemsSource = o;
    }

    ObservableCollection<int> o = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    private void buttonList1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.listBox1.Parent == null)
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(this.listBox1);
        else
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(this.listBox1);

        //this.listBox1.Visibility = this.listBox1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void buttonList2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.listBox2.Parent == null)
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(this.listBox2);
        else
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(this.listBox2);

        //this.listBox2.Visibility = this.listBox2.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void ButtonAddMore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        o.Add(o.Count);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try adding an object, then removing that object and adding it again while the item is out of the visual tree, you will see strange behavior. Furthermore, use a ContentControl.Content to set the item that should be in the layoutroot.